# How to get to know whether the checkbox is checked or not in a multiple choice listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, checked, multiple-choice

I am using multiple choice listview,in this I would am getting the position values when clicked on it.how to know whether it is checked or not.Kindly help me on this.Thanks.

Comment: please post your custom adapter class..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

and check if a particular view from the listView is checked with:

```
listView.isItemChecked(i) //i is the position of the view.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array `boolean[] selected`, where you save checkboxes state.

In your OnItemSelected method use this:

selected[position] = true or false